# How to make a variable frequency glitch-free square wave using STM32's HAL for driving stepper motors?

Tags: c, timer, stm32, stm32cubeide

This should be a common problem with a common answer. Common because this is how you communicate with a typical stepper motor driver (a4988, drv8825 etc.). This has a common answer which is very far from perfect. Writing to the ARR register directly has glitches, so it is recommended to have the preload enabled with this register. But then for an application like a self-balancing robot, the PID may want to set the rpm to 0, setting the ARR regiater to its maximum. With preload enabled, for a 32 bit timer, it will take hours to to have the next updated ARR value to take effect. I don't know the details, but I suppose there might be a HAL API to force a timer update, but this is already getting more complicated than it should be.

After searching for days, I have come across an application note by ST, AN2820, that is supposed to address this. But it is written in a very incoherent way, jumping from one topic to another without properly addressing any of it fully, and is unreadable to me. What little I have managed to understand tells me it also tries to do the same thing (changing ARR) but behind a DMA. Besides, I don't understand how it solves the aforementioned problem of 0 speed/rpm.

I will be glad if someone clears things up. How can this be achived in a simple way? What are the fundamental concepts/mechanisms to do this? How is a typical stepper driver implemented?

Addendum:
With a code like this for switching between 1Hz and 100Hz:

```
while (1)
  {
      TIM2->ARR = 1e6;
      TIM2->CCR1 = 1e6 / 2;
      HAL_Delay(1000);
      
      TIM2->ARR = 5000;
      TIM2->CCR1 = 5000 / 2;
      HAL_Delay(1000);
  }
```

I get the following buggy waveform :
[image]

Comment: Wouldn't you just stop the timer if you wanted to stop the motor?

Comment: @pmacfarlane I don't know, in absence of better options, I may have to. If I had this in a CNC machine or a 3D printer, then stopping the timer altogether makes sense, but in a  very fast PID control for keeping a structure upright, it is not desirable because in the very next iteration, it will want to start again.

Comment: It's not just 0 that's a problem. Any time the timer period is longer than the PID update rate, you're going to get into trouble. Ideally the timer period should always be significantly less than the PID update rate. Otherwise, you introduce a phase delay in the PID feedback that can destabilize the PID.

Comment: @user3386109 so what is the solution? This should be fairly common.

Comment: You may try: `cli(); ARR = val; CCR1 = val / 2; sti();` Otherwise, if you get interrupt between the setting of the regs you'll set one but not the other for the duration of any ISR. Also, use such a temp `int val = 1e6;` beforehand to move expensive floating pt outside the critical section

Comment: Don't forget you can manually trigger update event via TIMx_EGR event generation register, to force reload of the registers immediately.